# Name few internal classes which extends thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

is there any class in jdk which extends Thread class.
or the programmer only extends thread class?

I want to know the internal classes which extends thread.

Comment: To find if there are any direct subclasses you can check the Java API. According to the Java 8 API, `ForkJoinWorkerThread` is a direct known subclass. (See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html))

Comment: You can search for sub-classes in your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinWorkerThread.html), only [ForkJoinWorkerThread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinWorkerThread.html) **publicly** extends this class in the JDK. You can check it under "Direct Known Subclasses" at the top of the doc.

Comment: There is about a dozen internal classes, many which which add shutdown hooks. This is the only public one. +1